Tapping threads into aluminium profiles - Questions
I want to tap some threads into the centre of some 2020 aluminium profile.
Personally I've seen 2020 profiles that have a 4.2mm diameter core and a 5mm diameter core. They should take an M5 and M6 tap respectively.

What's the difference between hand taps and machine taps?
Should any decent tap set have three separate taps in it?
Am I making a terrible mistake buying dirt cheap taps off Aliexpress?
Is 1.0 Pitch standard for 'most' M6 bolts?

I would prefer using my cordless driver but if it's a really bad way to tap then I'd reconsider using a vice and hand tools.
Any advice? Thanks

Many taps have 3 flutes, but good ones can have 3 or more.
Cheap taps break due to quality and/or operator error.
M6 thread pitch can be 0.5, 0.75, 0.8 or 1 depending on application and material.
Quality taps will do many holes but cheap ones won't - do you have 10 holes to thread or 1000? Personally I buy quality tools...

Thanks I appreciate the input. I understand M6's can have many thread pitches, but I was under the impression that 1.0 was overwhelmingly used. Realistically I have under 50 taps to make in the next couple of years. I would love your input regarding using them with a hand tool vs a cordless driver. I guess a drill press would be the best option but that's not something I have right now. If I'm freehand tapping with a power tool, am I setting myself up for failure or if I have a steady hand and constantly reverse the tap, will it 'find it's own home' and I should be able to tap the aluminium?

If you have a good "touch" then tap with a drill , if not tap by hand. Making sure you are square is paramount in either case - getting a broken tap out is a b*tch...

Yeah the aluminium profile isn't cheap either. Thanks for your input. Any tips? Use copious amounts of cutting fluid? A special type?
